# SAT/ACT Math Simplify expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify the expression $\sqrt{a^2b^2}$, where $a < 0 < b$.

Is it equal to $-a\cdot b$?

Comment: It is unclear what is being taken the square root of. Also please format your question with MathJax and show your efforts in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
$$\sqrt{a^2b^2}=\sqrt{(ab)^2}=|ab|$$
Since $a\lt0$ and $b\gt0$, we have $ab\lt0$. Thus, $|ab|=-ab$.
$$\sqrt{a^2b^2}=-ab$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is correct.  In particular, we have
$$
\sqrt{a^2 b^2} = \sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{b^2} = |a|\cdot|b| = -ab
$$